# Import c++class from dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

If I want to import a C++ class from a DLL, which API should I use after `LoadLibrary()` returns?

I was searching in the following link, but I just found the `GetProcAddress()` and it seems like it will not work for a class.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: "import" is not a C++ concept (unless you mean the Microsoft-specific #import which is a compile-time operation (no LoadLibrary() needed.).  Are you trying to 1) create an instance of a class that is declared and defined in a DLL, or 2) use a class returned by a method in a DLL or 3)derive your own class from a base class declared/defined in a DLL, or [something else]....

Comment: “import” may not suitable ,I just want use a c++ class which in a DLL,I need a function to get it

Comment: Why are you calling LoadLibrary()?

Comment: i call it Because i need dll loaded into memory ,sorryI may not explain that clearly, my question is how to use a c++class in my program ,and the class is in a dll,and how should i write after LoadLibrary()?

Comment: Please see the linked question (over there ---> ) about __declspec and see if this answers your question.  If so, consider closing this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import a class using `LoadLibrary`.

You need to use a header file and an import library and link at compile time. The header file will use [`__declspec(dllimport)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy.aspx) to import the class.